# Empty result with GET request

Tags: angular

I want to implement Angular example which gets list from rest API. I tried this:

SQL query:

```
    @Override
    public Iterable<Merchants> findAll() {
        String hql = "select e from " + Merchants.class.getName() + " e";
        TypedQuery<Merchants> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Merchants.class);
        List<Merchants> merchants = query.getResultList();
        return merchants;
    }
```

Rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/merchants")
public class MerchantController {

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public Iterable<Merchants> getMerchantsList() {
        return merchantRepository
                .findAll();
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MerchantService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }    
  getList() {
    return this.http.get("...../api/merchants/list");
  }
}
```

**Component:**

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-terminal',
  templateUrl: './terminal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./terminal.component.scss']
})
export class TerminalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private terminalService: TerminalService,
              private merchantService: MerchantService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  } 

  merchants: Merchant[];

  ngOnInit() {   
    this.merchantService.getList().pipe(
      flatMap(params => {
          return this.merchantService.getList();
      })
    ).subscribe(value => {
      if (value != null) {
        this.merchants = value;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

But I get error when I try to use the component:

```
ERROR in src/app/panel/terminal/terminal.component.ts(57,9): error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Merchant[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
src/app/panel/terminal/terminal.component.ts(57,9): error TS2322: Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'Merchant[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Object'.
```

Can you give me some advice where I'm wrong?
Probably my typescript is somewhere incorrect?

Comment: The flatMap pipe makes no sense. You don't need any pipe. And you need to read the guide on HttpClient: https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response. Checking for null is also useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two suggestions which should address the issue. First, you are able to specify the return type of `getList`:

```
getList(): Observable<Merchant[]> {
  return this.http.get<Merchant[]>("...../api/merchants/list");
}
```

And second, I am not sure the `flatMap` operator is being used properly here. Unless you are specifically attempting to call the service again for each response, you can convert your call to:

```
this.merchantService.getList()
  .subscribe(value => {
    if (value != null) {
      this.merchants = value;
    }
  });
```